# Xml processor module not found error when try to consume soap service by using soap4r

Tags: ruby, soap, rhodes

I am trying to consume soap web service by soap4r gem. I am using

```
ryby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.4
soap4r 1.5.8
rhodes 3.2.3
```

I tried the following in IRB.

```
require "rubygems"
require "soap/wsdlDriver"


wsdl = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl"
driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl).create_rpc_driver

driver.wiredump_dev = STDOUT

params = {
"Celsius" => 32
}

driver.CelsiusToFahrenheit(params)
```

I got the response.
I tried the same in rhodes.

1. I add the extensions folder in rhodes app.
2. I copied the soap,wsdl,xsd and tags folders inside
   `\Ruby187\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\soap4r-1.5.8\lib` in my system.
3. I added soap as extension in my build.yml file
4. I required the following

   ```
   require 'soap/soap'
   require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
   ```

I am getting the following.

```
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:059 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: Product/product_controller
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:060 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: soap/soap
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:062 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/qname
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:063 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/charset
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:065 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/iconvcharset
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:066 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find iconv
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:067 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find nkf
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:067 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find uconv
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:067 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: soap/nestedexception
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:069 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: soap/wsdlDriver
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:074 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: wsdl/parser
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:076 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/datatypes
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:085 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: date
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:086 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: dateOrig
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:100 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: date/format
```

---

```
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:112 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/xmlparser
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:114 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/xmlparser/parser
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:115 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/ns
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:117 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/xmlparser/xmlparser
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:118 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find xml/parser
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:118 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/xmlparser/xmlscanner
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:120 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find xmlscan/scanner
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:120 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: xsd/xmlparser/rexmlparser
E 01/25/2012 11:07:08:121 000015ac              RhoRuby| require_compiled: error: can not find rexml/streamlistener
I 01/25/2012 11:07:08:121 000015ac                  APP| App error: XML processor module not found.
 C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/extensions/soap/xsd/xmlparser.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/extensions/soap/wsdl/parser.rb:12:in `require'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/extensions/soap/wsdl/parser.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/extensions/soap/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:9:in `require'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/extensions/soap/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/app/Product/product_controller.rb:3:in `require'
C:/Spritle/Projects/mobile_projects/netHTTPtrial/app/Product/product_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

After calling the `xmlParser` only throwing an error. I don't have any idea. 
If u know someone please help me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error.  Following the instructions in [this post](https://github.com/johngrimes/t-minus/issues/1) solved the problem for me:

At The beginning of soap4r/xsd/charset.rb
@internal_encoding = (RUBY_VERSION.to_f >= 1.9) ? 'UTF8' : $KCODE

Then Change line 66 in /soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/xmlparser.rb
into
c.to_s.downcase == name

Comment: If you want to understand what's really happening, please follow this link: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41231

Comment: Is there a more portable solution to this? I'm concerned others will not be able to run my Ruby app without making the same change.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line

```
  c.downcase == name
```

to
      c.to_s.downcase == name

in gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/xmlparser.rb, line76 worked for me. May be the older version treated a symbol as a string..

Answer (score 0):

I am running ruby-1.8.
I had to do name.downcase too to get this working.
c.to_s.downcase == name.downcase